# Analyzing the landuse in overlapping buffer area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, buffer

I want to do landuse regression. The reference points are 200m apart. I used buffer tool in Arcgis to draw areas of 500m to know the landuse area of the 500m radius buffer area. There were overlapping. Now, if I want to know, the area of 500m radius around every reference point. What should I do? There are lots of reference points.

Comment: Please be more specific when you talk about "I want to know the landuse". Are you talking about visual identification? Do you want to attach the landuse to the buffers? Do you need to do further processing? Are you interested in percentages? What data type is your land use layer? Why do you draw circles way larger than the distance between the reference points?

Comment: Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: 1. No, I am not interested in visual identification.                                                           
2. Yeah, Attaching the landuse to the bufferes will work for me i think. 
3. What I need is to know the area of land use pattern(Roads, Residential area, Industrial area etc) of those buffer area 
4. Yeas, I am interested in percentages.                                       
5. It is a shapefile
6. I need to know the land use pattern of those reference points in different radial distances. 

Thanks

Comment: Please use the [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/356586/edit) button to update your question, details in the comments most likely get lost.

Comment: In ArcGIS, you may utilize Zonal Statistics (Spatial Analyst) to identify area of different landcover pixels within each zone (buffer)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try the tool.